# Electron ipcMain undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The following code produces an error

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {});
```

This error is thrown in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

As mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964864/electron-typeerror-in-ipcmain-event-handler) question, i also tried using

```
const ipcMain = require('ipc-main');
```

but am getting the same error.

Seems that `ipcRenderer` is defined in the `electron` package, but not `ipcMain`. How do i fix this? Already tried reinstalling the latest nodejs and running `npm install` on a fresh checkout.

Answer (score 4):

In Renderer process you should use the counterpart of `ipcMain`, which is `ipcRenderer`. See [docs of `ipcMain`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) for code examples

Your corrected code would look like

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be that I loaded the module from a renderer process.
Moving the ipcMain related code to the main module (unsurprisingly) solved the issue.

Comment: Nothing interesting to add that's not already added to the question. Just that  the `const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;` should be used in the main module.